# How to express this "you are walking on a road and there is a hole in front of you, you accidentally drop 1 of your legs into it"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

You are walking on a road and there is a hole in front of you, you accidentally drop 1 of your legs into it.

[image]

**How would you express it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was walking down the road and I accidentally stepped in a big pothole.

Holes like this are called "potholes" and "dropping a leg in" would be "stepping in the pothole".  You need to adverb "accidentally" if you need to make that explicit (but if you don't mention it, people will probably assume it was accidental).